# Gridview checkbox checked changed event is not woring in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Checked or unchecked All Checkboxes inside grid with header checkbox   
        $("#<%= GridView_ManageUser.ClientID %> input[id*='checkbox_allcheckUncheck']").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is('checked'))
                    //Checkd All Child checkbox  
                    $("#<%= GridView_ManageUser.ClientID %> input[id*='CheckBox']").attr('checked', this.checked);
                else
                    //UnCheckd All Child checkbox  
                    $("#<%= GridView_ManageUser.ClientID %> input[id*='CheckBox']").removeAttr('checked', this.checked);
            });
            // Header checkbox checked or unchecked inside grid row checkboxes   
        $("#<%=GridView_ManageUser.ClientID%> input[id*='CheckBox']checkbox").click(function () {
                //Get All Checkbox inside grid  
            var GetAllCheckboxes = $("#<%=GridView_ManageUser.ClientID%> input[id*='CheckBox']checkbox").size();
                //Get number of checked checkboxes inside grid   
            var MarkcheckedCheckboxes = $("#<%=GridView_ManageUser.ClientID%> input[id*='CheckBox']checkboxchecked").size();
                //Check / Uncheck top checkbox if all the checked boxes in list are checked  
            $("#<%=GridView_ManageUser.ClientID%> input[id*='checkbox_allcheckUncheck']checkbox").attr('checked', GetAllCheckboxes == MarkcheckedCheckboxes);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="emailID" HeaderText="Email">
                            <ItemStyle Width="55%" CssClass="cssClass_hover" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />

                    <PagerStyle Height="50px" />
                    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="45px"></RowStyle>
                </asp:GridView>
```

trying to do checked or uncheck all checkbox within gridview . but header checkbox check changed event is not working here
This is my jquery code ..i am trying to check uncheck all checkbox of gridview but failed to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with simple code. Get the status of check/uncheck all status and assign that status to all checkboxes in the gridview.

```
    $("#<%= GridView_ManageUser.ClientID %> input[id*='checkbox_allcheckUncheck']").change(function () {
        $("#<%= GridView_ManageUser.ClientID %> input[id*='CheckBox']").prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
```

To get total number of checkboxes

```
var MarkcheckedCheckboxes = $("#<%=GridView_ManageUser.ClientID%> input[id*='CheckBox']").length;
```

To get total number of checked checkboxes

```
var MarkcheckedCheckboxes = $("#<%=GridView_ManageUser.ClientID%> input[id*='CheckBox']:checked").length;
```

Comment: but header checkbox event is not firing

Comment: perfect.. can u please tell how to get selected checkbox count

Comment: Edited answer to get total number of checkboxes and checked number of checkboxes